# Visual Studio - Background Highlighting

Tags: visual-studio, highlighting, add-on, source-highlighting

In notepad++ there is a function to highlight specific parts of code with a background-color. This is very usefull when the code grows up. Is there anything equal for Visual Studio (using the community-version here).

*Here's the function of notepad++:*
[image: style token]
[image]

Would be seriously very handy having this kind of highlighting possible in Visual Studio. Google wasnt a help so far. I mean, instead of searching for code 10% of the time I could better invest it into coding itself.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You can use bookmark instead.

Comment: I've only asked this to gain speed in coding. Bookmarks < Highlighting. I guess it wouldnt bring that much more efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

look at Tools-> Options-> Fonts and Colors -> Select Show Setting For and change Dispay Items to Highlight current line.

take care.

Comment: Dude. This is only highlighting the line according the caret. I want to highlight code persistent. So highlighting -> switching to somewhere else -> coming back and finding my highlighted text.